# Вложенные элементы Doctrine, Form

Tags: symfony2, symfony, doctrine

Есть класс Product

```
class Product {
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
 */
protected $name;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="products")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $category;

//...
}
```

Класс Category

```
class Category {
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Product", mappedBy="category")
 */
protected $products;

//...
}
```

Если я создаю создаю product и category одновременно, соединяю их и сохраняю, то все нормально

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$product = new Product();
$product->setName('thing');
$product->setPrice(123);
$product->setDescription('descp');

$category = new Category();
$category->setName('dasis');

$product->setCategory($category);

$em->persist($category);
$em->persist($product);
$em->flush();
```

Появляется строка в таблице category и в таблице product

**Проблема** Я хочу, используя форму, поменять **category**. 
Я использую EntityType, чтобы все категории подгружались в select

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => 'HlebBundle:Category',
            'choice_label' => 'name',
        ]);
}
```

После

```
if($form->isValid()) { ...
```

Получается такая штука

```
$product = [ id => '4',
        ...
        category => [
           id => 2
           name => category [
               id = 3
               name = "main category"
           ]
        ]
      ]
```

Т.е. в поле **name**, вместо названия записывается другая **category**.
это первое

---

и второе
если я пытаюсь сохранить (даже с этими некорректными данными)

```
$em->persist($product)
$em->flush()
```

почему-то отправляется запрос вида

```
UPDATE category SET name = ? WHERE id = ?
```

спрашивается, зачем мне обновлять имя категории, если я хочу поменять category_id в products

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема оказалась в том как я формирую форму
т.е. проблема оказалась именно во вложенности
приведу пример как было и как надо

Файл **ProductType.php**

```
class ProductType extends AbstractType {

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder
        ->add('name', TextType::class)
        ->add('price', NumberType::class)
        ->add('description', TextType::class)
        ->add('category', CategoryType::class)
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class);
    }
// ...
}
```

Файл **CategoryType.php**

```
class CategoryType extends AbstractType {
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder
        ->add('name', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => 'HlebBundle:Category',
            'choice_label' => 'name',
        ]);
    }
// ...
}
```

Из-за этого получается вложеность $product => category => name => Здесь находится объект **category**

---

Чтобы все работало, необходимо перенести код из **CategoryType.php** в **ProductType.php**

```
class ProductType extends AbstractType {
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder
        ->add('name', TextType::class)
        ->add('price', NumberType::class)
        ->add('description', TextType::class)
        ->add('category', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => 'HlebBundle:Category',
            'choice_label' => 'name',])
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class);
    }
// ...
}
```

И будет счастье
$product => category => **id категории**, которая после

```
$form->handleRequest($request);
```

Преобразуется в нужный класс, и

```
$em->persist($product);
$em->flush();
```

сохранит без ошибок